# How to fix the procedure

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, procedural-programming

Help me, please!
There's the procedure `operation[f_]`.
It works correctly and plot for functions:Cos,Sin. But, Unfortunately, it doesn't work for E^x and Log[E,x] and outputs errors, maybe because inputting not correct name of function or something else;(( What's the problem?

```
spxsin = {-1, -0.35, 0.3, 0.95, 1.6, 2.375, 3.15, 3.925, 4.7, 5.025, 
5.35, 5.675, 6};
spxcos = {-1, -0.75, -0.5, -0.25, 0, 0.775, 1.55, 2.325, 3.1, 3.825, 
4.55, 5.275, 6};
spxlny = {-1, 0.75, 2.5, 4.25, 6};
spxey = {-1, 0.75, 2.5, 4.25, 6};
operation[f_] := Block[{data},
data = Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, -1, 6, 0.1}];
Graphics[{Thick, Blue, Line[data],
Green, Table[Point[{spx[­[i]], f[spx[­[i]]]}], {i, 1, Length[spx]}],
Pink, Opacity[.7], 
Table[Rectangle[{spx[­[i]], f[spx[­[i]]]}, {spx[­[i + 1]], 
f[spx[­[i + 1]]]}], {i, 1, Length[spx] - 1}]
}, Axes -> True]]

Which[ f == Sin, spx := spxsin, f == Cos, spx := spxcos, f == E^x , 
spx := spxlny, f == Log, spx := spxey]

operation[Sin]
operation[Cos]
operation[E^x]
operation[Log]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Euler's E needs to be entered as Esc ee Esc.
It looks to me at you entered is a standard E.

Note also that Exp is the exponential function in Mathematica.

Comment: Thanks! Exp works! but unfortunately, Log doesn't work, though I edited spxey = {0.75, 2.5, 4.25, 6}; and data = Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, 1, 6, 0.1}]; Can You help me?

Comment: You write Log[E,x] in the question. Have you tried Log[x] ?

Comment: plain `E` works fine, you only need to do the `EscEsc` thing if you care what it looks like.. The trouble here is `E^x` is an expression, not a function that can take an argument.

Answer (score 2):

Edit now tested: you can pass pure functions to your `operation`, so instead of:  `operation[E^x]` try

```
 operation[E^# &]
```

or for example if you wanted a base 2 log it would be

```
 operation[Log[2,#]&]
```

A few other things to point out: `Log` fails simply because your `x` table range is negative.

Also, the `Which` statement you have doesn't do anything. Being outside your function, `f` is not defined so none of the conditionals are `True`.  Moving `Which` inside the function, this works:

```
 spxsin = {-1, -0.35, 0.3, 0.95, 1.6, 2.375, 3.15, 3.925, 4.7, 5.025, 
    5.35, 5.675, 6};
 spxcos = {-1, -0.75, -0.5, -0.25, 0, 0.775, 1.55, 2.325, 3.1, 3.825, 
   4.55, 5.275, 6};
 spxlny = {-1, 0.75, 2.5, 4.25, 6};
 spxey = {-1, 0.75, 2.5, 4.25, 6};
 operation[f_] := 
    Block[{data}, data = Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, -1, 6, 0.1}];
    Clear[spx];
    Which[
      TrueQ[f == Sin], spx := spxsin,
      TrueQ[f == Cos], spx := spxcos ,
      TrueQ[f == (E^# &)], spx := spxey ];
    Graphics[{Thick, Blue, Line[data], Green,
     Table[{PointSize[.1], Point[{spx[[i]], f[spx[[i]]]}]}, {i, 1, Length[spx]}],
     Pink, Opacity[.7], 
     Table[Rectangle[{spx[[i]], f[spx[[i]]]}, {spx[[i + 1]], 
       f[spx[[i + 1]]]}], {i, 1, Length[spx] - 1}]}, Axes -> True, 
          AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]]
```

Note each which test is wrapped in `TrueQ` to ensure it is either `True` or `False`  ( the test `Sin==Cos` is not false for all values and so does not return `False` )

```
 operation[Sin]
 operation[Cos]
 operation[E^# &]
```

[image]

Now if you want `Exp` to also work you need to explicitly put that form in your `Which` statement.  ( `f==(E^#&) || f==Exp` )